# Localhost page not found when not connected to internet on Rhomobile application

Tags: android, rhomobile, rhodes

I have an application build with Rhodes that runs well in many kinds of devices.

But, in a Samsung GalaxyTab with Android 3.2 it has a problem (GT-P6210).

The device doesn't have 3G, only Wi-Fi.

When Wi-Fi is enabled, it works fine.

When Wi-Fi is disabled, it works for some minutes and so it shows a page saying "Web page unavailable" and shows the URL (http://localhost:53899/app/....) exactly the same screen that appear on the Android's default browser when it do not find an URL.

If I copy the URL and go to the browser and try to access it so the page is loaded normally.

Do somebody has any idea of what could be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should post your question in launchpad, engineering can give a solution.

https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/rhomobile-suite/discussions

Comment: I've tried and they've reproduced the issue. I'm now waiting them to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: do you know how they went with this? I'm having the same problem but I dont see anything recently on the thread you created: https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/thread/2715

Comment: No, I think they haven't fixed it yet. Alternatively, we had suggested customers to not use devices which don't have 3G capabilities to avoid this problem. But I'm still waiting for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

On Launchpad there's currently a proof of concept to fix this:
https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/message/11817#11817